# Javascript sort array of objects alphabetically AND put first objects with value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I'm trying to sort this data which contains various arrays of objects, the console.log of **myData** is something like:

```
[
  {
    name: 'Cdb',
    image: 'xxx',
    coll: 'xxx'
  },
  {
    name: 'Bcd',
    image: 'xxx',
    coll: 'xxx',
    url: 'myurl'
  }
]
[
  {
    name: 'Abc',
    image: 'xxx',
    coll: 'xxx'
  }
]
```

I'm trying to sort it alphabetically (based on value of `name`) and if the *object* has the parameter `url` , put it at the beginning.

So the output would be:

```
    name: 'Cdb',
    image: 'xxx',
    coll: 'xxx',
    url: 'myurl'

    name: 'Abc',
    image: 'xxx',
    coll: 'xxx'

    name: 'Bcd',
    image: 'xxx',
    coll: 'xxx'
```

what I tried is this, and many variations of it, but it doesn't work:

```
var myData = props?.data

console.log(props?.data)

if(props.data){
  // those with url first, then alphabetically
  myData = props.data.sort(function(a, b){
    return b.url? 1 || (a.name < b.name) : -1;
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `!url` as a number (0 or 1) and subtract them:

```js
const arr = [{"name":"Cdb","image":"xxx","coll":"xxx"},{"name":"Bcd","image":"xxx","coll":"xxx","url":"myurl"},{"name":"Abc","image":"xxx","coll":"xxx"}]

arr.sort((a, b) => !a.url - !b.url || a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
  
console.log(arr)
```

This is saying that if exactly one of both has the `url` argument, that one should come first. Otherwise (if both have it, or neither have it) then the `name` is decisive.

This way, when multiple objects have the `url` argument, they will also be ordered among themselves by `name`.